# $0 < a_0 \leq a_1 \leq \cdots \leq a_n$, show $ p_n(z) = a_0 z^n + a_1 z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-1} z + a_n = 0$ has no root in $|z| < 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

> Assume $0 < a_0 \leq a_1 \leq \cdots \leq a_n$, show that equation
>   $$
> p_n(z) = a_0 z^n + a_1 z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-1} z + a_n = 0
> $$
>   does not have root in $|z| < 1$. Here $z$ is complex.

I started by considering the case in which $n = 2$, and tried to use the triangle inequality, while no progress was made. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want your coefficients in that order? If so, why?

Comment: @StellaBiderman This is a problem extracted from the textbook that I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\lvert z\rvert< 1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lvert (1-z)p_n(z)\rvert &= \left\lvert \sum_{k=0}^n a_{n-k}z^k - \sum_{k=0}^n a_{n-k}z^{k+1}\right\rvert\\
&= \left\lvert \sum_{k=0}^n a_{n-k}z^k - \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_{n+1-k}z^k\right\rvert\\
&= \left\lvert a_n - \sum_{k=1}^n (a_{n+1-k} - a_{n-k})z^k - a_0z^{n+1}\right\rvert\\
&\geqslant a_n - \sum_{k=1}^n (a_{n+1-k}-a_{n-k})\lvert z\rvert^k - a_0 \lvert z\rvert^{n+1}\\
&\geqslant a_n - \sum_{k=1}^n (a_{n+1-k} - a_{n-k}) - a_0\lvert z\rvert^{n+1}\\
&= a_0(1-\lvert z\rvert^{n+1})\\
&> 0
\end{align}$$

since $a_m \leqslant a_{m+1}$ and $\lvert z\rvert^k < 1$.